# R plotting, date on x axis

Tags: r

I know there are quite a few posts on plotting date values in axis. However, none seem to help. I basically want to have dates in the x-axis with the format "%d-%m-%Y". From the posts, this should be simply:

```
dat=read.table("TS.table",header=TRUE)
d=as.Date(dat$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
plot(d,1:length(d), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
axis.Date(1, at = seq(d[1], d[length(d)], by="month"),
    labels= seq(d[1], d[length(d)], by="month"),
    format="%d-%m-%Y", las = 2)
```

However, i get: [image]

You can find the text file with the dates [here](http://ubuntuone.com/11PXcukJ2R0vfhyVi4oxbG).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `labels` argument when you use `format`:

```
axis.Date(1, at = seq(d[1], d[length(d)], by = "month"),
          format = "%d-%m-%Y", las = 2)
```

[image]