# R: Character instead of level # on x axis when plotting?

Tags: r, plot, factors

I need help plotting month names on the x axis, instead of the level the months are assigned.  I am working with a "water year", so October is assigned to be level 1, and ending with September being level 12. I'm sure this is easy, I just don't often work with factors. Thanks!

Research Done:
[Plot a character vector against a numeric vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009203/plot-a-character-vector-against-a-numeric-vector-in-r)

[R plotting, date on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093446/r-plotting-date-on-x-axis)

Here is a simplified example of my data

```
    Months<-c("Jan"=4,"Feb"=5,"Mar"=6,"Apr"=7,"May"=8,"Jun"=9,"Jul"=10,
    "Aug"=11,"Sep"=12,"Oct"=1,"Nov"=2,"Dec"=3)

    Data<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

    df<-data.frame(Months,Data)

  >df
      Months Data
  Jan      4    1
  Feb      5    2
  Mar      6    3
  Apr      7    4
  May      8    5
  Jun      9    6
  Jul     10    7
  Aug     11    8
  Sep     12    9
  Oct      1   10
  Nov      2   11
  Dec      3   12

    plot(Data~factor(Months), df,las=2)
```

This puts the data in the correct place with the correct month, just the wrong labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `xaxt = "n"` in `plot` and then with `axis` change the `xaxis` tick labels

```
plot(Data ~ Months, transform(df, Months = match(row.names(df), 
                       month.abb)), las = 2, xaxt = "n", type = "b", col = "blue")
axis(1, at = seq_len(nrow(df)), row.names(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use argument to `plot` `xaxt = "n"` and then function `axis`.

```
plot(Data ~ factor(Months), df, las=2, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = factor(df$Months), label = row.names(df))
```

Comment: This axis function worked better, since it kept the correct order of months.